# SqlCacheDependency not working when using SqlCommand for cache-key

Tags: c#, .net, caching, sqlcommand, sqlcachedependency

This code works fine, it invalidates the data whenever it is changed in the database:

```
    AggregateCacheDependency aggDep = new AggregateCacheDependency();

                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand ocom = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
                SqlCacheDependency SqlDep = new SqlCacheDependency("DBNAMEINCONFIG", "Products");    
                aggDep.Add(SqlDep);
```

I cannot have a straight invalidate on the entire "Products" table though, I need to be able to invalidate a selection on the table.  The problem I'm having is the following code does not ever invalidate the cache when the data is changed:

```
AggregateCacheDependency aggDep = new AggregateCacheDependency();

            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand ocom = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
            ocom.CommandText = "SELECT ID,ClinicID,Price,Enabled FROM dbo.Products WHERE ClinicID = 1";
            ocom.Connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBSTRING"].ToString());
            SqlCacheDependency SqlDep = new SqlCacheDependency(ocom);

            aggDep.Add(SqlDep);
```

I tried to include all the information necessary to analyze this, but please let me know if I should include more!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, according to the rules outlined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aewzkxxh%28VS.80%29.aspx), that you cannot use `SELECT *` for the query.

The following change should solve your issue:

```
ocom.CommandText = "SELECT ClinicID FROM Products WHERE ClinicID = 1";
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I updated the SELECT statement, but the problem still exists where the cache is not invalidated even if something in the table (and the SELECT statement) changes.

Comment: Ah, maybe try adding specific columns that do change to the select statement. I am a little unclear on exactly how the underlying mechanism works, but it may be watching columns in the select statement itself.

Comment: I updated the opening post with the current code.  Changed this line: ocom.CommandText = "SELECT ID,ClinicID,Price,Enabled FROM dbo.Products WHERE ClinicID = 1";

Comment: It still doesn't invalidate the cache even when the SELECT statement looks like it conforms to the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

As **competent_tech** pointed out there are quite a few rules for the queries used to build `SqlCacheDependency`.
According to this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h91hx359.aspx) article the most important are:

1. Do not use SELECT * or table_name.* in your queries.
2. You must use fully qualified table names (e.g. dbo.Products).

Beside those rules it is important to execute the `SqlCommand` used to build the `SqlCacheDependency` in order to enable the query notification:

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = ocom.ExecuteReader())
{
  while (reader.Read())
  {           
  }
} 

SqlCacheDependency SqlDep = new SqlCacheDependency(ocom);

aggDep.Add(SqlDep);
```

Hope, this helps.

Comment: Hans, I tried executing the command before creating the SqlCacheDependency object, but still no luck with it invalidating the cached object.

Comment: @GregSnider: Could you please send a more complete code sample (how do you initiialize the SqlCacheDependency infrastructure)?